# How do you compare two Images Edge Descriptors?

Tags: java, histogram, edge-detection

Hi i am totally new to image retrieval and i currently implementing a fucntion to retrieve image from database that matche the most the entred image. I have choosen two descriptors via the jfeaturelib library, these two are color histogram and Mpeg7Edege descriptor.
For the RGB color histogram, i found on this very forum that this if you want to compare two of them you only have to do  mean of the euclidian distances of each points like this

```
double dist(vector<double> *histogram1, vector<double> *histogram2) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (vector<double>::iterator val1=histogram1->begin(), val2=histogram2->begin();
         val1<histogram1->end();
         val1++, val2++) {
        result += (*val1 - *val2) * (*val1 - *val2);
    }
    result = sqrt(result);
    return result;
}
```

Does also this apply to the Mpeg7Edge histogram ? I also want to know if this histogram always return the same number of features independently of the image size, because i have tried it with two images and in both cases it'Ls returning 160 feautures.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as being the author of JFeatureLib I hadn't watched for issues here (just on the mailinglist).
Sure, you **can** use the euclidean dist on these vectors. For higher dimensional vectors (10+ or 20+) you might want to consider the [cosine dist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_distance) as it ususally provides better results. But this is something you might simply test in your application.
And yes, the histogram should always yield the same amount of dimensions.